# Best way to parse a string, based on delimiters?

Tags: arrays, string, file, parsing, fortran

If we have a string of form `a="2016:03:30:00:00,2,5,10,,,,,"` what is the best way to specify and extract the *n*th element, delimited by the *n-1*th comma? Eg. 2nd element is after 1st comma.

Right now I'm pulling data from a huge CSV file, comma delimited, row by row into a string array. Each row of the array will have the form above (could or could not have values in nth column), and each row has the same number of delimiters.

I'm trying to work on only specific columns, so that I can average them, etc., but cannot find a way to isolate the *n*th column. `SCAN` and `INDEX` don't seem to help when there are multiple occurrences of the character in question.

Alternatively, is there some way to read the file and assign only the *n*th columns to my string array? I couldn't find a way to do that without taking in the whole CSV line into one array element, so am now hoping parsing the string in each row would be the next best thing. But if I can read this into the array, parsed into multiple columns to start with, that would be ideal.

Aside: Is Fortran the wrong language for this type of task? I could backup and do this in C or even an ugly bash script if needed, but trying to make this in family with other Fortran applications running in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP writes *we have a string of form a="2016:03:30:00:00,2,5,10,,,,,"* so let's go with that, the program has already read a line from the file into a character variable called `a`.  It also seems that the line starts with a date/time and then has a fixed number of integer elements, some of which may be absent.  Given a declaration such as

```
character(len=128) :: elements
```

we can simply trim off the first 17 characters (ie the date and the first comma) of `a` by executing

```
elements = a(18:)
```

which assigns to the character variable `elements` the contents of `a` with the date stripped off.  So after the preceding statement `elements` should look like

```
"2,5,10,,,,,"
```

We can now use Fortran's list directed input to read the 7 integers in `elements`, with a statement such as

```
read(elements,*) nums(1:7)
```

Now one can do with `nums` what one will, such as keeping only the 4th element and recycling the others.

This isn't a complete answer, but I hope it gives OP enough to figure out the rest.  If not, clarify the question.

Comment: This idea worked, thank you! 
But what is going on with the line "elements = a(18:)"? In practice the 18 needs to be one larger than the number of characters to cut, in the example, including the first coma, it's 17. 

I thought Fortran indicies started at 1, which would imply 17, but testing this show's your right at n+1.

Comment: The `18` is the position of the first character in the line that we are interested in; the date and the first comma occupy the first 17 characters.  So the substring `a(18:)` is the rest of the line, from the 18th character to the end.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is basically the same as HighPerformanceMark's answer (i.e., use list-directed input for comma-separated values), but I experienced trouble (= End-of-file) when a line ends with comma (e.g., lines 3 and 4 below). So, I manually added one more comma to each line to deal with that case:

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: nrow = 4, ncol = 9
    character(100) :: csvinp( nrow ), time
    integer :: dat( nrow, ncol ), irow, icol

    csvinp( 1 ) = "2016:03:30:00:00,2,5,10,1,2,34,5,3,2"
    csvinp( 2 ) = "2017:03:40:00:00,1,2,,4,,,,,9"
    csvinp( 3 ) = "2018:03:50:00:00,,2,3,,,,7,,"
    csvinp( 4 ) = "2019:03:60:00:00,,,,,,,,,"

    do irow = 1, nrow
        csvinp( irow ) = trim(csvinp( irow )) // ","   !! add one more comma
    enddo

    dat(:,:) = 0        !! (#)
    do irow = 1, nrow
        read( csvinp( irow ), * ) time, dat( irow, : )

        print *, "irow:", irow
        print *, "  time    = ", trim( time )
        print *, "  columns = ", dat( irow, : )
    enddo

    print *
    print *, "average of each column:"
    do icol = 1, ncol
        print *, "icol=", icol, "ave=", sum( dat( :, icol ) ) / real(nrow)
    enddo
end
```

Results:

```
 irow: 1
   time    = 2016:03:30:00:00
   columns =  2 5 10 1 2 34 5 3 2
 irow: 2
   time    = 2017:03:40:00:00
   columns =  1 2 0 4 0 0 0 0 9
 irow: 3
   time    = 2018:03:50:00:00
   columns =  0 2 3 0 0 0 7 0 0
 irow: 4
   time    = 2019:03:60:00:00
   columns =  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

 average of each column:
 icol= 1 ave= 0.75
 icol= 2 ave= 2.25
 icol= 3 ave= 3.25
 icol= 4 ave= 1.25
 icol= 5 ave= 0.5
 icol= 6 ave= 8.5
 icol= 7 ave= 3.0
 icol= 8 ave= 0.75
 icol= 9 ave= 2.75
```

Here, it seems better to fill `dat` initially with some desired value (e.g., 0), because if the string has blank columns, the corresponding element of `dat` is not modified. For example, if we change the Line (#) in the above code to `dat = -100`, we get

```
 irow: 1
   time    = 2016:03:30:00:00
   columns =  2 5 10 1 2 34 5 3 2
 irow: 2
   time    = 2017:03:40:00:00
   columns =  1 2 -100 4 -100 -100 -100 -100 9
 irow: 3
   time    = 2018:03:50:00:00
   columns =  -100 2 3 -100 -100 -100 7 -100 -100
 irow: 4
   time    = 2019:03:60:00:00
   columns =  -100 -100 -100 -100 -100 -100 -100 -100 -100

 average of each column:
 icol= 1 ave= -49.25
 icol= 2 ave= -22.75
 icol= 3 ave= -46.75
 icol= 4 ave= -48.75
 icol= 5 ave= -74.5
 icol= 6 ave= -66.5
 icol= 7 ave= -47.0
 icol= 8 ave= -74.25
 icol= 9 ave= -47.25
```

Although I'm not sure if this behavior is standard-conforming, it was the same among gfortran-6, ifort-16, and Oracle fortran 12.5. (Actuallly, I expected the compilers to fill 0 when there are blank columns, but it was not the case.)

Comment: To avoid the end of file error (which I also got), I've been using a read call such as "read(unit,*,END=40)" where it jumps out to label 40 and continues. 

I'll have to study the line
 "read( csvinp( irow ), * ) time, dat( irow, : )" because this is also what I've been trying to grasp - but it looks like this works. Thanks!

Comment: If I'd done more thorough testing I would probably have used the `iostat` argument on the `read` statement to deal with the problem arising with lines ending in a comma.  That would take care of a whole range of malformed lines.

Comment: If you change the ':' to ',' then you can read the data the way that @HighPerformanceMark mentioned and still have yyyy,mm,dd etc be able to be read in.